# How to reference a composite primary key in GORM?

Tags: go-gorm

Golang's GORM library supports composite primary keys. But how to reference them from related models?

For example, suppose I have a User and a Note model:

```golang
type User struct {
    OrganizationID uint   `gorm:"primaryKey; not null"`
    Name           string `gorm:"primaryKey; not null"`
}

type Note struct {
    ID             uint   `gorm:"primaryKey; not null"`
    OrganizationID uint   `gorm:"not null"`
    UserName       string `gorm:"not null"`
    User           User
}
```

The auto migrator creates the `notes` table like this, which fails:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "notes" ("id" bigserial NOT NULL,"user_name" text NOT NULL,"organization_id" bigint NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
CONSTRAINT "fk_notes_user" FOREIGN KEY ("user_name") REFERENCES "users"("name"))
```

But I want it to do this instead:

```sql
CONSTRAINT "fk_notes_user" FOREIGN KEY ("user_name", "organization_id") REFERENCES "users"("name", "organization_id")
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `ForeignKey` and `References` tags. They are mentioned in the [docs](https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html#Override-References), although in the reversed (One-to-Many) context.

```golang
type User struct {
    OrganizationID uint   `gorm:"primaryKey; not null"`
    Name           string `gorm:"primaryKey; not null"`
}

type Note struct {
    ID             uint   `gorm:"primaryKey; not null"`
    OrganizationID uint   `gorm:"not null"`
    UserName       string `gorm:"not null"`
    User           User   `gorm:"ForeignKey:OrganizationID,UserName;References:OrganizationID,Name"`
}
```

AutoMigrate will generate the following sql:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users` (`organization_id` integer NOT NULL,`name` text NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`organization_id`,`name`))

CREATE TABLE `notes` (`id` integer NOT NULL,`organization_id` integer NOT NULL,`user_name` text NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`),CONSTRAINT `fk_notes_user` FOREIGN KEY (`organization_id`,`user_name`) REFERENCES `users`(`organization_id`,`name`))
```

Comment: Your comment doesn't seem right, references should be "OrganizationId,UserName" and foreignKey should be "OrganizationID, Name". References describes the struct fields of the relating table, foreignkey describey the fields of the target table